# wifi-ap snap getting disabled in ubuntu core and raspberry pi 3

Tags: networking, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi, wireless-access-point

Im working on a Raspberry Pi 3 with ubuntu core. I'm trying to use wifi-ap snap to get an access point. However, the ap gets disabled all time. I set:

```
sudo wifi-ap.config set disabled=false
```

but it changes again to true after some seconds. I check it with:

```
sudo wifi-ap.status
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Network manager is connected to the hardware?
(I assume you are using network-manager snap as you are using wifi-ap)
You can check by

```
nmcli d
```

In case all devices are unavailable, it might be it is configured that you are using systemd-networkd.

You can configure AP on boot, you can use netplan, where you can configure in

```
sudo vi /etc/netplan/00-snapd-config.yaml
```